# A Hausdorff atom in lattice of group topologies

Tags: gn.general-topology, examples, topological-groups

Do you have an example of an infinite Hausdorff nonabelian topological group $(G,\mathcal T)$ such that for any nontrivial group topology $\mathcal S$ on $G$ with $\mathcal S\subseteq \mathcal T$ we have $\mathcal S = \mathcal T$?

Comment: I assume, which is a standard, that only Hausdorff spaces are considered in the context of topological groups. Then **arbitrary** compact group would do. Mentioning groups in this context does not add anything to the topological situation when only examples are needed.

Comment: ‏@WłodzimierzHolsztyński: In some contexts only Hausdorff group topologies are considered. But Hausdorffness is not part of definition. By [these comments (click link)](http://65.54.113.26/Publication/16030379/atoms-and-antiatoms-in-the-lattice-of-group-topologies) , an abelian group cannot have Haussdorff atom. So group structure matter. btw, I do not have access to this paper and just read the abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any compact group with no nontrivial normal closed subgroups has this property, since there can be no coarser Hausdorff topology and in any coarser non-Hausdorff topology the closure of the identity would be a normal closed subgroup in the original topology.  For instance, this includes all (centerless) compact simple Lie groups.

Comment: Do you have an example of a centerless compact simple Lie group, assuming that I just know a definition of  Lie groups?

Comment: There may be a problem with *Any* in your answer. In fact the topology must also be nontrivial. So there must be at least three distinct group topologies on the group.

Comment: The smallest example is $SO(3)$.